# Point of discontinuity of $f(x)=[x]sin(\frac{\pi}{[x+1]})$

Tags: functions

If $f(x)=[x]sin(\frac{\pi}{[x+1]})$, where $[.]$ denotes the greatest integer function, then the points of discontinuity of f in the domain are______

My approach is as follow

$[x+1]\ne0$

we need to exclude this region from the domain

$0\le x+1<1$, hence the region that needs to be excluded form the domain is $-1\le x<0$

Not able to proceed from here

Answer (score 1):

You are right about excluding $[-1,0)$.

Now observe that on $(n,n+1)$ the function has the constant vale $n\sin (\frac {\pi} {n+1})$. Hence it is continuous on this  interval for each $n$. Now show that each integer point  (other than $-1$) is a point of dis-continuity by observing that $[x]$ jumps by one unit when you go from left to right, but $n\sin (\frac {\pi} {[x+1]})$ tends to a non-zero value as $x$ approaches $n$.